# "neo4j.com.example.entity.ExtendedObject is not a known entity" when mapping data to ExtendedObject

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
@Node("label")
public class Object extends  Auditable<String> implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    ....
//getter 
//setter
//constructor


}


public class ExtendedObject extends Object{

    private Long projectId;
    private String projectName;
    private Long clientID;
 
// extra field which i don't want to store in entity but want to retrieve while fetching the Object


}


@Repository
public interface ObjectRepo extends Neo4jRepository<Object, Long> {

@Query("")
List<ExtendedObject> findPosition(@Param("comparison") String comparison);

}
```

I provided necessary annotation whenever necessary.

I want to map the query result into an `ExtendedObject`, but it's throwing error:

```
neo4j.com.example.entity.ExtendedObject is not a known entity
```

Comment: This may have nothing to do with your issue, but:  is a **very bad idea** to name one of your own classes `Object`, since that is easily confused with the standard `java.lang.Object`. Also, you can forget to import your package and use the standard `Object` when you don't mean to. Or you can try to use one `Object` class and accidentally use the other. Besides, you should use a more descriptive name for your own classes.

Comment: @cybersam i provided the name according to convention and requirement in my code base, here its just for example, i'm aware about the naming convention and design principles, thank you for attention.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Spring Data Neo4j needs the return type of a repository method to match whatever object we are extending for the repository itself. For instance, if the ObjectRepo is extending the Neo4jRepository<Object, Long>, then all methods in the repository must return a type of Object. Otherwise, SDN doesn't know how to map the result. To correct this, you can change the repository to the ExtendedObject and return that subentity.

I've created a sample repository showing this with all the instructions to reproduce. https://github.com/JMHReif/extendedobject-not-known-entity-exception

Also, as a side note, you can use the @ReadOnlyProperty annotation in the ExtendedObject class to ensure that you only read the property and don't write to it. An example of using that is also included in the Github project above. :)